# I can't seem to copy the rows in CFGRID and paste them

Tags: coldfusion, paste, cut, cfgrid

I am trying to copy the text in a cfgrid but it simply wont copy anything. The cfgrid format is HTML. I do not want to make the grid editable, I just want the user to be able to cut and paste what is in the cfgrid.

Thanks

Comment: limitation of cfgrid.  You may want to generate the excel file and open that file in browser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Limitation of the underlying ExtJS grid. You may be better off writing a selection event handler, i.e. the user selects (clicks on) a row, and that data is saved to the users clipboard (could be blocked by security features), or pops up in a modal dialog, inside a textarea, for easy cut and paste.

For more info on writing that selection handler you'll want to search out the ExtJS docs for version 3.1 (for CF 9) or 2.2 (for CF 8).